# What does the word "란" mean in TOPIK exam?

Tags: grammar, meaning, phrase-meaning

I read in the answer section of the TOPIK exam that there are a few words "답란" and "결시 확인란". Why is there the word "란" in these words? What does this word "란" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From naver dictionary:
[답란](https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/entry/koko/5916e03459474060a2a575ae07cdd4d9) ->

답란 答欄
Pronunciation
형태  [+答-欄]
뜻풀이부
noun

1. 시험지 따위에서, 답을 적는 난.
   다음 문제를 읽고 보기에서 맞는 답을 골라 답란에 적으시오.

If we search for the meaning of 欄, this is specified as both 란 and 난 in Korean.

Meaning of 난 is

```
(신문등의) a column; a page; a section; (기입하는) a blank
```

So I suppose it means the blank space where you're supposed to fill in your answer, and the space where you're supposed to confirm your attendance.

Comment: Note: as an independent word, you read it “난,” and as a suffix, you read it “-란.”